# SAS Data Integretation Studio : error if lookup returns multiple values

Tags: sas, data-integration

Currently, in our DI studio job we have a couple of lookups. When one of these lookups for a certain record returns multiple values, the lookup will choose one of them (I think the first one) to select. I would actually prefer to receive an error because for me it means the lookup is not yet well defined and I probably need to add extra 'where' expressions.

Is there an option to set it this way? I can not find any at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

If you are comfortable with macro, one option might be...

```
%macro get_lookup(&in_where);
    proc sql noprint;
        select
            lookup_value,
            count(lookup_value)
        into
            :l_lookup_result,
            :l_count_results
        from lookup table
        where &in_where;
    quit;

%if l_count_results = 1 %then %do;
    %global g_lookup_result;
    %let g_lookup_result = &l_lookup_result;
%end;
%else %do;
    %put ERROR: Lookup did not return expected 1 result.;
    %raise_error; 
%end;

%mend get_lookup;

%get_lookup(&where_clause);
```

It's a bit cumbersome, but it'll get the job done. Unless it returns more than one value in which case it will fall over. Gracefully. 
Notes: I've assumed you build up some lookup-related where clause in macro variable &where_clause, which is then used to populate the macro parameter &in_where. I've also assumed you have a macro defined called %raise_error - otherwise, if this lookup doesn't set the value of &g_lookup_result, any susbequent code that attempts to use the macro variable will fall over.